# Phonegap 2.5 - Some functions not working on Android 2.3.6 & Under

Tags: javascript, cordova, module

This is a very general question and maybe difficult to ask, but the thing is that I have a Phonegap aplication with two buttons in the main page.

One button is to list all the customers I have in my database, and the other button is to synchronize the database, so the user can download de customer's information from the server.

On Android 4.0 and over, it works great, but, when I run it on Android 2.3.6 and under, the synchronization button stops working. This the code:

HTML

```
<div data-role="button"><img src="images/synch.png" class="iconGrid"  onclick="syn()"/></div>
```

JS

```
function syn(){
    alert(0);
    var synchronizationManager = new Test.mobile.SynchronizationManager();
    synchronizationManager.synchronize();
}
```

JS 2

```
Test.mobile.SynchronizationManager = function(){    
    function synchronize(){
        alert(1);
        synchronizeCustomers();
    }
    function synchronizeCustomers (){
        alert(2);
    }
return {

    synchronize:synchronize

};
```

};

So fat, only 0 and 1 messages show up. It never gets to alert(2). Once again, this happens only in Android 2.3.6 and under. In Chrome and Android 4.0 it works just fine!

Im really stuck here. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you write some more details?

Comment: Are you able able to log the `this` inside each function? (synchronize and synchronizeCustomers)